# Python threading.Timer not waiting before executing function

Tags: python, multithreading, python-multithreading

I have thrown together a quick threading test:

```
import threading

def test():
    print "it don't work"
while True:
    threading.Timer(1, test).start()
```

It runs test, but it doesn't wait. What's wrong?

Comment: Runs fine (as expected) in _Pyhton27_. But you should put a `time.sleep` in that loop, to avoid killing the CPU.

Answer (score 2):

In each loop iteration, you start a new thread. Therefore you will reach the limit of allowed thread and you will get an exception : `can't start new thread.`

```
while True:
    threading.Timer(1, test).start()
```

You can add global flag and wait until the function is executed - You should use time.sleep to avoid busy waiting.

```
a = False
def test():
    global a
    print("hallo")
    a = True
threading.Timer(10, test).start()
while not a:
    time.sleep(1)
print('done')
```

Comment: I guess that I should have been more specific. I am trying to put this timer in a game event loop, so it needs to run serpratly from the rest of the program.

Comment: Well, After calling `threading.Timer.start` - you have two threads , the main thread and a thread which run the function in delay and exits.